# If there any alternative for IDurableOrchestrationContext SetCustomStatus method for big payload?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

In durable function runtime I'm getting the error message:

> The UTF-16 size of the JSON-serialized payload must not exceed 16 KB. The current payload size is 17 KB

I'm using IDurableOrchestrationContext SetCustomStatus method ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.durableorchestrationcontextbase.setcustomstatus?view=azure-dotnet-legacy))

I have nugets installed:
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v1.029
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask v2.2.2

So the question is how can I extend this limit or what alternative shouId I use for bigger payload?

Comment: "*Large message support is intended for function inputs and outputs. We don't currently have plans to increase the limit for custom status values. I suggest instead manually uploading large status messages to blob storage and then exposing the blob URL as the custom status value.*" - from github https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/26

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks, it's very helpful. Is there any 'best practice' example how to implement this?